# ElasticSearch - Both full text match and 'fuzzy' match

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have data in ElasticSearch that contains information about Vehicles, and I'd like the columns to be both "full column match" searchable and "fuzzy" searchable (i.e. the same as MySQL `LIKE '%%'`).

The issue I'm having is that the spaces in the values are causing it to be thrown off, so I added a `not_analyzed` index to each of the values that need to be searched in this way but I still can't get it to work how I want it to..

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are multi fields for this problem. Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/_multi_fields.html

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves my problem? Maybe I'm not understanding how to use them

Comment: I've implemented the multifield now, but having trouble storing data in it and querying it. Do I have to explicity store data in the field itself and also the nested `raw` field? @Mantas

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't see your first comment. If you want to access nested field use "." to specify which field you want to use. For example if you have "title" and fields "raw" and "custom_analyzed" you can reference specific field in queries with "title.raw" and "title.custom_analyzed" respectively.

Comment: Ah, awesome. Do I just store data in the `title` field and it will automatically fill the others? Also, what would happen if I just queried `title`? Would it query it as an analyzed field?

Comment: Sadly, the link is not working anymore. Can you please update the response with an example or quote of what you wanted to say ?